# Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I'm fairly new to Angular. But when I try to start my project with

```
ng serve --open
```

I got the following error:

[image: error]

My project structure is like this:

[image: structure]

What can be the problem?

Comment: You just need to be sure that you are at the root directory of the application, also check the `angular.json` if it has any structure issue

Comment: Instead of link outside images in your text, copy them and paste in your editing window; it will be easier for whom is interested in this Q&A site to get the whole picture, and probably easier to reward you too.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72670696/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Navigate to root folder in terminal and then run angular cli command. Below command will put you in root directory from current location =>
cd angular_t-project

Comment: this is a confusing answer.  Was there once a "below command"?

Answer (score 37):

To fix error “This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace Error”, do right-click on your project's name in Visual Studio Code and click the “Open in Integrated Terminal” option.

It would open the project to your terminal and the error would be fixed. Now you would be able to run the command **“ng serve –open” or "ng serve"** into your terminal without any issue.

Comment: This solution works for me but can you explain a bit more why this works? Thanks

Comment: Did not work for me (win 11). Oddly, ng serve works, but ng add does not.

Comment: @Phoebe because it sets the current directory as the project root directory so the cli can locate the configuration files

Comment: What is a "project" in VS Code? Folder? Workspace? A project file?

Answer (score 30):

In my case, `angular.json` file is automatically deleted when setting up `Nx Console`. I just use `git` to revert the `angular.json` deletion to fix this error.

Answer (score 10):

I encountered this issue and finally worked it out.

In my case, that's the missing file issue: for some unknown reason, my Angular project lost its *angular.json* file, which should be located in the project root directory.

As this was a tutorial project (*angular-tour-of-heroes*), I downloaded a sample from the official website. By comparing the two projects, soon I found the difference. I copied it from the sample to mine and did a minor change in *angular.json* (different project name).

Finally I ran `npm install` and `ng build`, and the world returned...

So for a similar issue, maybe you should check the *angular.json* file first because this JSON content defines "sourceRoot".

Comment: When I'm running `ng build` I'm receiving the initial error again.

Answer (score 7):

When it becomes difficult on *ng new my-project*, use the following (`--save-dev`) to update the local version to the latest in your folder where you wish to create a new project:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 4):

It's easy:

Note: Please stay in your root folder and then run the commands in the terminal. (Whatever name of your app you gave while creating the app using the `ng new appname` command, use that "appname" only in the following command.)

Step 1: Run command `cd appname`

Step2: Then run `ng serve -o`

It must solve the issue if other ways are not working.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was the following. A few days before exploring [Angular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)), I just tried [JHipster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JHipster), with Angular.

My bad; I used the JHipster command in the root folder on a Mac (users/${currentUser}). So, I have the *angular.json* file in there. It seems that Angular scans folders from the root, stumble upon this file and breaks its internal logic.

After cleaning up this folder from JHipster files (including *angular.json*) everything works smoothly. I suggest you to check your root folder for the presence of redundant files that might break Angular.

Answer (score 1):

This issue arises when you try to run `ng serve` in another folder; i.e., instead of the root folder where your README.md file and other .json configurations are present.

Comment: This may happen if you unzip a file and the project is further down in the folder hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the folder of your newly created project.

For example, if you created `hello-world`:

```
ng new hello-world
cd hello-world
ng serve
```

The reason for your mistakes (and mine, btw) was that we were trying to start the server from outside the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has said, you have to be in the root folder.

If you using Visual Studio 2019/2022, use the Terminal/PowerShell:

```
cd C:\Users\<user>\source\repos\<solution>\<projectname>\ClientApp
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace.

Check you are in the file or not (folder → cd project file).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. It turns out it was related to the position in my directory.

If you want to build or serve an Angular project, you have to be in the root directory of your project.

Hint: To determine if you're in root project, type the "ls" or "dir" command. If the command prompt shows you all Angular files, like "angular.json", "package.json", etc. you're in the root folder.

Once you're in the root folder, you could execute these commands.

Comment: '[dir](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dir)' actually works on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that there are more than one answer for this problem and none of the given here solved my problem.

I am running inside the project's folder, and I was working with it normally. Then I needed to create a new component and I stumbled on this error.

All the other commands worked, like `ng serve`, etc..
I also checked the *angular.json* file, and it was there, not corrupted...

I made a full new project from zero, and went inside the projects folder, tried `ng n c myComponent` and I got that error again...

This started after an `ng cli update`.

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer, more like a report.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you unzip a project file, and the project is actually further down in the unzipped folder hierarchy.  Like others have said, check your current working directory and verify that you are in the project root folder.

Comment: This doesn't appear likely. Can you substantiate the claim?