# Cant create an Angular Project. - This command is not available when running the Angular CLI inside a workspace

Tags: angular

I created a new empty folder "myapp". Inside this empty folder I opened my Windows Terminal.

`ng new app`

But I got this Error: Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI inside a workspace.

I tried many folder, on different hard drives. Its allways same.

**Update:**

Even in older already created Angular project I cant use ng command.

e.g. `ng g c mycomponent` inside of already created angular project not work with exact same error message.

**Update 2:**
When I use the command `ng v` on desktop or some empty folder. I go this hint.

> Your global Angular CLI version (14.2.7) is greater than your local
> version (14.2.1). The local Angular CLI version is used.

This is impossible because im not inside an angular project. So I think for some reason the **cli is always conntected/linked to one of my projects?**

**What I tried**

1. Uninstall/Install Angular latest with cache clean.
2. Used git bash, cmd, powershell, windows terminal.
3. Used different harddrives, folders, projects.
4. Restarted PC.
5. Uninstalled anglular cli  and uninstalled nodejs 16
6. Installed nodejs 18 and angular latest

Comment: Does this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72670696/error-this-command-is-not-available-when-running-the-angular-cli-outside-a-work#:~:text=To%20Fix%20Error%20%E2%80%9CThis%20command,and%20error%20would%20be%20fixed. solve your problemm

Comment: same here. `ng new` suddenly started throwing that error message. Tried with both node 16 and node 18, because I have nvm installed. I did not touch my node 16 env since days, now in node 18 env `ng new` stopped working, so I just for diagnostic reasons switched to node 16 env with nvm, and `ng new` does not work there either. No even the same version. (on node 18 env v15.2, on node 16 env 15.1.5) Must be a configuration thing, some global configuration went wrong, my guess, but no idea how to fix it....

Comment: @Jovana, definitely no. Please read the OP, he is trying to do something in an **empty** folder, namely `ng new`

Comment: Same here. Npm command and Nx are working, but ng and ionic command are down. So to run it is `npm start` or `nx serve`

Comment: It may be caused by the vscode migration from angular CLI to Nx.  It is so easy to click yes on the lil pop-up without really knowing what it will do.

Answer (score 0):

In my case somewhere way upper in the directory path (practically in the drive root) accidentally an angular.json was created/dropped...

After deleting that, everything is working fine.

I would revise your diagnostic point #3 regarding *different drives*, as it is not possible to have common root for multiple drives, (unless a misfortunate symbolic link?).

So either your case and my is different, or your #3 regarding *different drives* needs to be revisited.